# Database timeout in Azure SQL

Tags: azure-sql-database

We have a .Net Core API accessing Azure SQL (Gen5, 4 vCores)

Since quite some time,
the API keeps throwing below exception for a specific READ operation

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout
> Expired.  The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

The READ operation has code to read rows of data and convert an XML column into a specific output format.
Most of the read operation extracts hardly 4-5 rows @ a time.
The tables involved in the query have ~ 500,000 rows

We are clueless on Root Cause of this issue.

Any hints on where to start looking @ for root cause?

Any pointer would be highly appreciated.

NOTE : Connection string has following settings, apart from others

> MultipleActiveResultSets=True;Connection Timeout=60

Overall code looks something like this.

HINT: The above timeout exception comes @ ConvertHistory, when the 2nd table is being read.

```
HttpGet]
public async Task<IEnumerable<SalesOrders>> GetNewSalesOrders()
{
    var SalesOrders = await _db.SalesOrders.Where(o => o.IsImported == false).OrderBy(o => o.ID).ToListAsync();
    var orders = new List<SalesOrder>();

   foreach (var so in SalesOrders)
   {
    var order = ConvertSalesOrder(so);
    orders.Add(order);
   }

   return orders;
}

private SalesOrder ConvertSalesOrder(SalesOrder o)
{
    var newOrder = new SalesOrder();    
    var oXml = o.XMLContent.LoadFromXMLString<SalesOrder>();    
    ... 
    newOrder.BusinessUnit = oXml.BusinessUnit;  
    var history = ConvertHistory(o.ID);     
    newOrder.history = history; 
    
    return  newOrder;
}

private SalesOrderHistory[] ConvertHistory(string id)
{
    var history = _db.OrderHistory.Where(o => o.ID == id);
    ...
}
```

Comment: What's the actual SQL you run? Seems like your query is taking a lot of time to complete.

Comment: await _db.SalesOrders.Where(o => o.IsImported == false).OrderBy(o => o.ID).ToListAsync();

_db.OrderHistory.Where(o => o.ID == id);

The above 2 are the only 2 actual SQL statements.
We are using Entity framework to fetch data

NOTE : We have also executed update Stats in Azure SQL, but that does not help.

Comment: That's a C# instruction, not the real SQL ran at the server. What's the final query you submited? Also, what columns and indexes are in the table being queried?

Answer (score 2):

> Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Execution Timeout Expired. The timeout period elapsed prior to completion of the operation or the server is not responding.

From [Microsoft Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/connect/timeout-expired-error),

You will get this error in both conditions **Connection timeout** or **Query or command timeout**. first identify it from call stack of the error messages.

If you found it as a connection issue you can either Increase connection timeout parameter. if you are still getting same error, it is causing due to a network issue.

from information that you provided It is Query or command timeout error to work around this error you can set **`CommandTimeout`** for query or command

```sql
    command.CommandTimeout = 10;
```

The default timeout value is 30 seconds, the query will continue to run until it is finished if the time-out value is set to 0 (no time limit).

For more information refer [Troubleshoot query time-out errors](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/sql/performance/troubleshoot-query-timeouts) provided by Microsoft.